# How to submit a form in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to know if it is possible to send a form which is not in react component by fetch in react component.

```
<form action="json.bc" class="form_search" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="Firstname" value="">
  <input type="hidden" name="Familyname" value="">
  <!-- ... -->
</form>
<div id="Result"></div>
```

The form `class="form_search"`is outside of the `<div id="Result"></div>`. I want to submit the form in react component.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      data: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("/json.bc", {
      method: "POST"
    })
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(text => {
        var Maindata = JSON.parse(text.replace(/\'/g, '"'));
        this.setState(
          state => ({
            ...state,
            data: Maindata
          }),
          () => {}
        );
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    const renderInfo = data.map((item, i) => {
      return <span>{item.name}</span>;
    });
    return <div class="loading_content">{renderInfo}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("Result"));
```

Actually I want to have another fetch() request in component to submit this form also I can not add the form in component.

Comment: How you can't add form in component?

Answer (score 0):

Add on Form tag onSubmit event `<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>`

you will need a button also inside of Form which will submit the From.

```
<button>Submit</button>
```

Comment: Hi @Nikola . But as I said the form is out of component.

Comment: It is not possible to have `onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}`

Comment: Hi @bita ok, when you said "form is out of component", do you mean form is in another parent or child component?

Comment: No. I mean it is completely out of React code. (Sorry I am new to React:| hope you will get what I am mean )

Comment: The form is a kind of researching. I want when form is submitted the content of `<div id="Result"></div>` be updated.(As you can see the action of form is the same as  `fetch("/json.bc", {...}`)